# error handling with python lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have lists being created by a program and depending if a value exists I want to do something further. If not, I want to `pass`.

For example:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]

if a.index(6):
    print "in"
```

I get the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c.py", line 6, in <module>
    if a.index(6):
ValueError: 6 is not in list
```

How do I search for a value in a python list and do something if I find the number?

Comment: Somebody also ought to mention that if your elements are hashable and if you're planning on doing a lot of membership testing, a better data-structure might be a `set`:  `a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `index` to test if something is in a list.  `index` assumes the item you are searching for is already in the list.  Furthermore (and as you know), if it can't find it, it throws an error.  Instead, use the `in` keyword:

```
if value in lst:
    # value was found in lst
```

See an example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> 6 in a
True
>>> 7 in a
False
>>>
```

So, your code should be this:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]

if 6 in a:
    print "in"
```

Answer (score 3):

you can make a condition like this:

```
if "a" in list:
    #do stuff
```

where `"a"` is what you're searching for in the list

if you want to do it the way you have it in youre code try a `try/except` block like so:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
try: 
    #try this code
    if a.index(6):
        print "in"
except ValueError:
    #do this if there is an error
    pass
```

Comment: Blanket `except`? Bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 6 in a:
```

`in` tests containment. `index` gives the index of something you know is in the list.